# Отдельное модальное окно для каждого объекта Angular

Tags: html, angular5, angular, компоненты

Пишу на Angular 5, это компонента, где выводятся все "мнения", хочу что бы при клике на кнопку конкретного мнения, появлялось модальное окно, где будет выводить больше информации, что-то типа кнопки **Подробнее**.

```
<div class="opinion-blocks">

    <div class="opinion-block" *ngFor="let opinion of opinions">

        <p class="opinion-block-header">{{opinion.objective.description}}</p>
        <p class="opinion-block-text">
            {{opinion.text}}
        </p>
        <p class="opinion-block-author">{{opinion.author.lastName}} <br> {{opinion.author.firstName}}</p>
        <p class="opinion-block-category">{{opinion.objective.category.type}}</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" (click)="openModal()">More</button>

        <div class="back" [ngStyle]="{'display':display}"></div>

        <div class="modal" [ngStyle]="{'display':display}">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">                      
                        <h2>Header</h2>
                        <button type="button" class="close" 
 (click)="closeModal()">Close</button>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-content">
                    <p>{{opinion.author.lastName}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>  

</div>
```

Вот код самой компоненты:

```
export class OpinionListComponent{

    public opinions: Opinion[];

    display="none";

  constructor(private opinionsService: OpinionsService,
    @Inject(windowProvider.provide) private window: Window) { }

   ngOnInit() {
    this.opinionsService.getOpinions()
      .subscribe(opinions => {
        this.opinions = opinions;
            });
    } 

    openModal(){
        this.display="block";
    }

    closeModal(){
        this.display="none";
    }
}
```

Соотвественно, при клике на любую кнопку, отображаются все окна одновременно.
Как привязать кнопку к конкретному блоку, и может есть лучше способ реализовать данную задачу. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: К сожалению, сейчас нет времени, чтобы написать полноценный ответ. Суть решения в том, что вы оставляете **одно** модальное окно на всю вьюху, в функцию `openModal()` передаёте при клике конкретный opinion, а в её код добавляете что-то вроде `this.modalLastName = opinion.author.lastName` (ну или `this.modalOpinion = opinion`, если в модалке надо много данных показать). И собственно в модалке уже отображаете `<p>{{modalLastName}}</p>`

Comment: Блин, спасибо, как я и сам не додумался до такого решения

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста, заходите ещё :)